# REACT NATIVE PICKER - TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.updateMonth')

Tags: react-native, picker

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { YearPicker, MonthPicker, DayPicker } from 'react-dropdown-date';
import { StyleSheet, Image, View, Text, ScrollView, TextInput, Picker, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const TextAndInput = ({ text, placeholder, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.textInputContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.inputLabel}>{text}</Text>
      <TextInput onChangeText={ onChange } placeholder={placeholder} style={styles.input}/>
    </View>
  );
}
const MonthPickInput = ({ text, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.textInputContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.inputLabel}>{text}</Text>
      <Picker itemStyle={styles.pickerItem} onValueChange={onChange} mode="dialog" style={styles.picker}>
        <Picker.Item label="January" value={1} />
        <Picker.Item label="February" value={2} />
        <Picker.Item label="March" value={3} />
        <Picker.Item label="April" value={4} />
        <Picker.Item label="May" value={5} />
        <Picker.Item label="June" value={6} />
        <Picker.Item label="July" value={7}/>
        <Picker.Item label="August" value={8} />
        <Picker.Item label="September" value={9} />
        <Picker.Item label="October" value={1} />
        <Picker.Item label="November" value={2} />
        <Picker.Item label="December" value={3} />
      </Picker>
    </View>
  )
}
const DayPickInput = ({ text, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.textInputContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.inputLabel}>{text}</Text>
      <Picker itemStyle={styles.pickerItem} onValueChange={onChange} mode="dialog" style={styles.picker}>
        <Picker.Item label="1" value={1}/>
        <Picker.Item label="2" value={2}/>
        <Picker.Item label="3" value={3}/>
        <Picker.Item label="4" value={4}/>
        <Picker.Item label="5" value={5}/>
        <Picker.Item label="6" value={6}/>
        <Picker.Item label="7" value={7}/>
        <Picker.Item label="8" value={8}/>
        <Picker.Item label="9" value={9}/>
        <Picker.Item label="10" value={1}/>
        <Picker.Item label="11" value={2}/>
        <Picker.Item label="12" value={3}/>
        <Picker.Item label="13" value={4}/>
        <Picker.Item label="14" value={5}/>
        <Picker.Item label="15" value={6}/>
        <Picker.Item label="16" value={7}/>
        <Picker.Item label="17" value={8}/>
        <Picker.Item label="18" value={9}/>
        <Picker.Item label="19" value={1}/>
        <Picker.Item label="20" value={2}/>
        <Picker.Item label="21" value={3}/>
        <Picker.Item label="22" value={4}/>
        <Picker.Item label="23" value={5}/>
        <Picker.Item label="24" value={6}/>
        <Picker.Item label="25" value={7}/>
        <Picker.Item label="26" value={8}/>
        <Picker.Item label="27" value={9}/>
        <Picker.Item label="28" value={1}/>
        <Picker.Item label="29" value={2}/>
        <Picker.Item label="30" value={3}/>
        <Picker.Item label="31" value={4}/>
      </Picker>
    </View>
  )
}
const YearPickInput = ({ text, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.textInputContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.inputLabel}>{text}</Text>
      <Picker itemStyle={styles.pickerItem} onValueChange={onChange} mode="dialog" style={styles.picker}>
        <Picker.Item label="2020" value={4} />
        <Picker.Item label="2019" value={3} />
        <Picker.Item label="2018" value={2} />
        <Picker.Item label="2017" value={1} />
        <Picker.Item label="2016" value={9} />
        <Picker.Item label="2015" value={8} />
        <Picker.Item label="2014" value={7} />
        <Picker.Item label="2013" value={6} />
        <Picker.Item label="2012" value={5} />
        <Picker.Item label="2011" value={4} />
        <Picker.Item label="2010" value={3} />
        <Picker.Item label="2009" value={2} />
        <Picker.Item label="2008" value={1} />
        <Picker.Item label="2007" value={9} />
        <Picker.Item label="2006" value={8} />
        <Picker.Item label="2005" value={7} />
        <Picker.Item label="2004" value={6} />
        <Picker.Item label="2003" value={5} />
        <Picker.Item label="2002" value={4} />
        <Picker.Item label="2001" value={3} />
        <Picker.Item label="2000" value={2} />
        <Picker.Item label="1999" value={1} />
        <Picker.Item label="1998" value={9} />
        <Picker.Item label="1997" value={8} />
        <Picker.Item label="1996" value={7} />
        <Picker.Item label="1995" value={6} />
        <Picker.Item label="1994" value={5} />
        <Picker.Item label="1993" value={4} />
        <Picker.Item label="1992" value={3} />
        <Picker.Item label="1991" value={2} />
        <Picker.Item label="1990" value={1} />
        <Picker.Item label="1989" value={9} />
        <Picker.Item label="1988" value={8} />
        <Picker.Item label="1987" value={7} />
        <Picker.Item label="1986" value={6} />
        <Picker.Item label="1985" value={5} />
        <Picker.Item label="1984" value={4} />
        <Picker.Item label="1983" value={3} />
        <Picker.Item label="1982" value={2} />
        <Picker.Item label="1981" value={1} />
        <Picker.Item label="1980" value={9} />
        <Picker.Item label="1979" value={8} />
        <Picker.Item label="1978" value={7} />
        <Picker.Item label="1977" value={6} />
        <Picker.Item label="1976" value={5} />
        <Picker.Item label="1975" value={4} />
        <Picker.Item label="1974" value={3} />
        <Picker.Item label="1973" value={2} />
        <Picker.Item label="1972" value={1} />
        <Picker.Item label="1971" value={9} />
        <Picker.Item label="1970" value={1} />
        <Picker.Item label="1969" value={2} />
        <Picker.Item label="1968" value={3} />
        <Picker.Item label="1967" value={4} />
        <Picker.Item label="1966" value={5} />
        <Picker.Item label="1965" value={6} />
        <Picker.Item label="1964" value={7} />
        <Picker.Item label="1963" value={8} />
        <Picker.Item label="1962" value={9} />
        <Picker.Item label="1961" value={1} />
        <Picker.Item label="1960" value={2} />
        <Picker.Item label="1959" value={3} />
        <Picker.Item label="1958" value={4} />
        <Picker.Item label="1957" value={5} />
        <Picker.Item label="1956" value={6} />
        <Picker.Item label="1955" value={7} />
        <Picker.Item label="1954" value={8} />
        <Picker.Item label="1953" value={9} />
        <Picker.Item label="1952" value={1} />
        <Picker.Item label="1951" value={2} />
        <Picker.Item label="1950" value={3} />
      </Picker>
    </View>
  )
}
const RegisterButton = ({title, color, onPress, width }) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1}}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress = { onPress } style = {styles.registerButton}>
        <Text style = {styles.registerButtonText} > { title } </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

function Register({ changePage }) {
  const [ username, updateUsername ] = useState('');
  const [ password, updatePassword ] = useState('');
  const [ firstName, updateFirstName ] = useState('');
  const [ lastName, updateLastName ] = useState('');
  const [ month, updateMonth ] = useState('');
  const [ day, updateDay ] = useState('');
  const [ year, updateYear ] = useState('');

    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
      <TextAndInput text="Create a username. This is the name that others will see you as publicly." placeholder="Username" onChange={() => updateUsername(username)} />
      <TextAndInput text="Create a secure password." placeholder="Password" onChange={() => updatePassword(password)} />
      <TextAndInput text="Enter your first name. This will help calculate your numerology. This name will not be shown publicly." placeholder="First Name" onChange={() => updateFirstName(firstName)} />
      <TextAndInput text="Enter your last name. This will help calculate your numerology. This name will not be shown publicly." placeholder="Last Name" onChange={() => updateLastName(lastName)} />
      <MonthPickInput text="Enter the month that you were born." onChange={() => this.updateMonth(v)} />
      <DayPickInput text="Enter the day that you were born." onChange={() => this.updateDay()} />
      <YearPickInput text="Enter the year that you were born." onChange={() => this.updateYear()} />
      <RegisterButton onPress = {() => changePage("account") } title="Register" />
      </ScrollView>
    )
};

export default Register;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
    paddingVertical: 15,
    paddingHorizontal: 30
  },
  textInputContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
  input: {
    height: 50,
    flex: 1,
    flexShrink: 0,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    color: 'black',
    marginVertical: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#eee',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    fontSize: 20,
    borderRadius: 50
  },
  inputLabel: {
    fontSize: 16,
    paddingHorizontal: 20
  },
  registerButton: {
    height: 50,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    borderRadius: 50,
    marginVertical: 50,
    marginHorizontal: 30
  },
  registerButtonText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: "white",
  },
  picker: {
    marginVertical: 10,
    marginHorizontal: 30,
  },
  pickerItem: {
    fontSize: 20,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    height: 50,
  }
});
```

When I select an item from the Picker Component I get a

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
> '_this.updatedMonth')

This error message would apply to all of the pick components that I've rendered.

Is it an issue with how my states are initialized?
Is it an issue with the values of the Picker.Items being integers?
Is it an error with how to function is passed to the component?

Can someone help me understand why I am receiving this error so I know how to do this correctly moving forward.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get arguments from your callbackMethod as below

```
   <MonthPickInput text="Enter the month that you were born." onChange={(v) => 
    this.updateMonth(v)} />
```

You are passing an argument 'v' to this.updatemonth(v), so it should be a dynamic value from above callback that is onChange as I wrote above.